# Need to set a value of a Text field in a in outlook addin, based on whether the selected email is Inbox or SentItems in Outlook

Tags: email, outlook, office-js, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I'm working with a Outlook Add-in. I need to set value of a text field as "Outgoing" or "Incoming" based on the selected outlook mail which is used to load outlook Add-In.

I tried Office.js library in React using Office.context.mailbox.item as follows:

useEffect(()=>{

const emailItem = Office.context.mailbox.item;

```
if (emailItem.location === Office.MailboxEnums.LocationType.Inbox) {
  setPostType("Incoming");
} else if (emailItem.location === Office.MailboxEnums.LocationType.Sent) {
  setPostType("Outgoing");
}
```

}, []);

Answer (score 0):

Location property is for an appointment not mail. Currently the feature for getting an email's folder, is not a part of the product. We track Outlook add-in feature requests on our [Tech Community Page](https://aka.ms/M365dev-suggestions). Please submit your request there and choose the appropriate label(s). Feature requests on Tech Community are considered, when we go through our planning process.

As a workaround for marking mails as incoming outgoing, properties from [user profile interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.userprofile?view=outlook-js-preview) can be compared with [from](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.messageread?view=outlook-js-preview&preserve-view=true#outlook-office-messageread-from-member) or [sender](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.messageread?view=outlook-js-preview&preserve-view=true#outlook-office-messageread-sender-member) interface properties.

As a workaround to determine folders, graph apis can be used. You can get the folderId from message using [get message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/message-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) , fetch the folder using [get mailFolder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/mailfolder-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) and get the folder name from response.
For marking emails as incoming and outgoing, 'from' property of message also be used.